# ( : ) character appended to data while making Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, ajax

Getting some strange issue. A ( : ) character is getting append to the JSON sent to the server by AJAX request.

[image]

This ( : ) colon character, while its not there when i just print the JSON on console.

[image]

Using this code to make AJax request.

```
 var json = JSON.stringify(plans);
        $.ajax({
            url : 'localhost/test',
            type : 'POST', 
            data : encodeURIComponent(json),
            success :  function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
  });
```

Already tried removing the `encodeURIComponent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ISSUE SOLVED**

```
var json = JSON.stringify(plans);
        $.ajax({
            url : 'localhost/test',
            type : 'POST', 
            data : { data : encodeURIComponent(json) },
            success :  function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
  });
```

I was missing the variable name that will carry the json.